# Separate Sonar report for Jmeter and Selenium

Tags: selenium, jmeter, sonarqube, alm

I am using SonarQuber Version 5.6.4.
I want to integrate Jmeter and Selenium report separately within Sonar.
Currently both reports are coming under same count. How can I show 2 separate reports for Jmeter and Selenium?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've looked at `SonarQube`, but can't you just specify the project in the [analysis parameters?](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) Then you could just run it once for each project?

Comment: I have 2 TRX file. 1 from Nunit and 1 from Selenium. But while passing it from Jenkins it Sum up the result